# Windows Batch file, get the current folder the recursive function is in

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm walking through the file tree for all files

```
FOR /R "N:/somewhere/far/away/" %%A IN (.) DO (
 Pushd %%A
 Echo now in %%A
)
```

"Echo now in" will say  N:/somewhere/far/away/0001  for example.

How can i get just the 0001 part of this variable for use elsewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a run:

```
@echo off
FOR /D /R "N:\somewhere\far\away\" %%A IN (*) DO (
   Pushd "%%A"
      Echo now in "%%~nxA"
   popd
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another for loop that looks at the path as a string in `%%A` and grabs the name of last directory -

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R "N:/somewhere/far/away/" %%A IN (.) DO (
    FOR /F "delims=\" %%B in ("%%~pA") do set dir=%%B
    Pushd %%A
    Echo now in !dir!
)
```